# Why GLatLng() doesn't receive variables?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i have the following code to update a google map:

```
function updateit(c1,c2){
alert(c1+"-"+c2); // This works
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(c1, c2), 13); // But this doesn't
}

updateit(37.4419, -122.1419);
```

The alert  is working and show the two coordinations, but i think the GLatLng() doesn't receive them, so the map is not updated unless i directly declare them as strings :

```
function updateit(c1,c2){
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13); // This works
}
```

How to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You don't show enough code to diagnose the problem.  What's the context in which `updateit()` is called?  Where do `c1` and `c2` come from?  You say "declare as string" but you show them as Numbers. Needs more detail/background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, this really isn't enough

This code could be all your app does - logically it isn't and so much more is happening around it.

This looks absolutely sound. I'm simply guessing you have c1 and c2 mixed up. *what does your alert say?*

`37.4419, -122.1419` heads straight to 1708 Fulton St

reverse them and it goes no where. Google maps does not find `-122.1419, 37.4419`

check that buddy.

Comment: You are right! i really reversed them and spent hours finding the solution XD

Comment: its easily done - I was spitting feathers today to the reason why my route was going backwards - "BUT I SAID GLASGOW TO EDINBURGH!!!", got my fields back to front o_O

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [Google AJAX API Loader](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/)? If so I believe you have to use the google.maps.* namespace:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(c1, c2), 13);
```